# What is wrong with this CrossTab query?

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, crosstab

I have a line of code that creates a CrossTab query in MS Access that is producing an error.

Here is the code:

```
Dim cmd4 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("TRANSFORM First(y.Daily_Growth) AS FirstOfDaily_Growth Select y.Ticker FROM Daily_Growth_Rates AS y GROUP BY y.Ticker ORDER BY y.[Date] DESC PIVOT y.[Date]", Nordeen_Investing_3.con)
```

Here is the error:

```
Additional information: Too many crosstab column headers (7326).
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to `PIVOT` on dates.  If the date range is something like a full year, then you would exceed the [255 maximum columns](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-2007-specifications-HA010030739.aspx) for a table or query.

If you want to `PIVOT` on dates, you must select a narrower date range.  See whether the query can work with data from a single month.

Comment: How do I limit the date range to 8 months?

Comment: `WHERE y.Date >= #2013-1-1# AND y.Date < #2013-9-1#`

Comment: How do I make this dynamic?  So it always gets the past 8 months?

Comment: Convert to a parameter query and feed it the date parameters from your VB.Net code.

Comment: Using today's date as an example I would want every day from 9/25/13 back to 1/14/2013.  And then tomorrow, I would want every day from 9/26/13 to 1/15/13.  And so on.

Comment: I would never have guessed Jan 14 thru Sep 25 for the past 8 months.  But that doesn't matter.  You know the start and end of your target date range.  So use a parameter query and pass it those dates from VB.Net.

Comment: It's a little more than 8 months.  I'm just trying to use the maximum amount of fields.  What do you mean by use parameter query?  You mean I should create a parameter query first and then use a CrossTab query after that to restructure it how I want it?

Comment: Yes.  Do it in the Access query designer.